# Euler Numbers A000295 And Basic MMA Code

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

When I run this snippet in MMA

```
Map[Fold[Plus[#, ##] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, Range[8]]
(* {{1}, {4}, {11}, {26}, {57}, {120}, {247}, {502}} *)

(* or *)
Map[Fold[Plus[##, #] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, Range[8]]
```

These are: from OEIS: A000295 *[Eulerian numbers](https://oeis.org/A000295) (Euler's triangle: column k=2 of A008292, column k=1 of A173018).*

Obviously, the function calls, of #1 & ## (all the rest) &; must be duplicating a pattern of:

```
Table[2^n - n - 1, {n, 20}]
```

Mr. Weisstein on the same OEIS page.

Why is this? Is it fundamental to MMA & it's pure functions approach?

Comment: Would it help you understand if I rewrote the first snippet as `Map[Fold[Plus[#1, #1, #2] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, Range[8]]`?

Comment: If I try `Map[Fold[Plus[#1,#1,#2+1]&,{0},Range[#]]&,Range[5]]` this makes A095151. Another triangle sequence, part of Bells Triangle. I think, I get it. It is just all about repetition/recursion?

Comment: Or another form: `Map[Fold[Plus[#1, #2, #2] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, Range[10]]` (1) A002378 Oblong (or promic, pronic, or heteromecic) numbers: a(n) = n*(n+1), (2) Denominators in Harmonic Triangle. (3) A103505 Denominator in expansion of `(1-x)*Log[1-x]`.

Comment: Series expansion of: `f[x_] := (1 - x)*Log[1 - x]; Series[g[x], {x, 0, 10}]` produces: {2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, .. } as denominators. Interesting.

Comment: In fact, in the current version, you could omit the `{0}`, so: `Map[Fold[Plus[#1, #1, #2] &, Range[#]] &, Range[8]]`.  Your last one can also be done as `Map[Fold[Plus[#2, ##] &, 0, Range[#]] &, Range[10]]`. In any case, please look up `#` and `##` in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I can understand, just the nature of SlotSequences and the patterns they exhibit. Spouse if I study //Trace? Should probably ask more on Euler Triangle numbers to Maths SE. ** Answer would be, just showing, how the recursion tree is performed, if anybody wants to try?

Comment: @code9910743 Have you tried replacing `Fold` with `FoldList`? The latter will show you each step taken to the final result, if you want to see how you go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map[FoldList[Plus[#, ##] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, Range[8]] // ColumnForm
(* Out
{
 {{{0}, {1}}},
 {{{0}, {1}, {4}}},
 {{{0}, {1}, {4}, {11}}},
 {{{0}, {1}, {4}, {11}, {26}}},
 {{{0}, {1}, {4}, {11}, {26}, {57}}}
} *)
```

Comment: This result is correct, but I am not sure that it answers the question.

Comment: The differences are the Mersenne numbers A000225. Good enough for me.

Comment: Looking at: Map[FoldList[Plus[#1, #1, #2] &, {0}, Range[#]] &, {3}] // Trace